# SQL Correlated Subquery in Select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, correlated-subquery

Is it possible to create a correlated subquery in SELECT just like this?

```
SELECT  EmployeeID,
EmployeeName,
ManagerID,
    (SELECT EmployeeName FROM tblEmployee WHERE EmployeeID = ManagerID)
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE EmployeeID = '12345';
```

The ManagerID should be equal and should be the ManagerID of Employee '12345'.

The purpose of the subquery is to fetch the Manager's Fullname based on its ID.
I highly appreciate your response.
I am a newbie. 
Thanks, 
Rye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  To simplify your SQL writing, remember to always qualify all column names when your query has more than one table reference:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName, e.ManagerID,
       (SELECT m.EmployeeName
        FROM tblEmployee m
        WHERE m.EmployeeID = e.ManagerID
       )
FROM tblEmployee e
WHERE e.EmployeeID = '12345';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's a more simpler yet easier to understand/ready query

Comment: Should i add DISTINCT keyword before m.EmployeeName ?

Comment: No - if `tblEmployee.EmployeeID` has a valid unique constraint, the subquery is guaranteed to return a maximum of 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @tblEmployee TABLE(EmployeeID INT,EmployeeName VARCHAR(100),ManagerID INT)
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES(1,'Arun',2)
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES(2,'Dinesh',NULL)


SELECT  EmployeeID,
EmployeeName,
ManagerID,
    (SELECT M.EmployeeName FROM @tblEmployee M WHERE T1.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID)ManagerName
FROM @tblEmployee T1
WHERE EmployeeID = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I got the data by using this query.

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName, e.ManagerID, m.EmployeeName as ManagerName 
FROM tblEmployee e 
JOIN tblEmployee m
ON e.ManagerID = m.EmployeeID
WHERE e.EmployeeID = '12345';
```

Thanks for all who posted their response.
Never would have solved it without you guys.
Thanks,
Rye